# Proof that the natural numbers are unique (up to isomorphism)

Tags: real-analysis

This is Theorem 1.28 in [Schröder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FIYI8O2) along with the beginning of the proof in which I have a simple question.

> The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are the unique subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the properties of Theorem 1.23.

*Proof:* Suppose there is a set $S\neq \mathbb{N}$ with properties as in Theorem 1.23. Then $S$ is a successor set, so $\mathbb{N}\subseteq S$. Let $B = S\backslash \mathbb{N}$. Then $B$ is nonempty, and hence by the Well-ordering theorem, which is valid for $S$, $B$ has a smallest element $B$. (etc)

Now my question is, the Well-ordering theorem states

> Every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a smallest element.

How can it be that $S$ has a smallest element, since $\mathbb{N}\subseteq S$ but the Well-ordering theorem requieres the opposite, that $S$ is a subset of the natural numbers?

For completeness I attach Theorem 1.23:

> There is a subset $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, called the natural numbers, so that
>
> 1. $1\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> 2.For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the number $n+1$ is also in $\mathbb{N}$.
>
> 3. Principle of induction. If $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is such that $1\in S$ and for each $n\in S$ we also have $n+1\in S$, then $S= \mathbb{N}$.

Also, if it's because the point 3 in this last theorem is fulfilled, i.e. $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, then we can straight away say that $S=\mathbb{N}$. Why bother at all to construct $B$?

Comment: You can deduce the principle of well ordering from the principle of induction. If your $S$ satisfies the principle of induction, then it satisfies the well ordering principle.

Comment: That's one of the exercises that I have done. As far as I can see it, it's a confusing proof by contradiction.

Comment: I don’t know how *you* prove it. The proof I generally give is by **contrapositive**, not contradiction; but it is common for many people to mistakenly cast proofs by contrapositive as proof by contradiction. In any case, given that $S$ will necessarily be well-ordered, you are not invoking the well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$, but the one inherent in $S$.

Comment: I think it's clear the abuse of notation from Brian's answer.

Comment: I think it’s confusing notation, not technically abuse; but that is irrelevant to whether you prove well-ordering from induction by contradiction or by contrapositive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say that $S$ has the properties listed in Theorem 1.23, we mean that if $\Bbb N$ is replaced by $S$ in the statement of Theorem 1.23, then $S$ has the resulting properties. Unfortunately, the symbol $S$ already appears in that statement with a different meaning, so we also have to replace it with a different symbol, say $A$, that is not already in use in the statement of the theorem. Thus, the hypothesis is that $S$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. $1\in S$.
2. For each $s\in S$ the number $s+1$ is also in $S$.
3. If $A\subseteq S$ is such that $1\in A$ and for each $s\in A$ we also have $s+1\in A$, then $A=S$.

This clearly does not immediately say that $S\subseteq\Bbb N$. It does, however, imply that $S$ is well-ordered: just imitate the proof that $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered, using these properties of $S$ instead of the corresponding properties of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Ok thanks. This abuse of notation drove me mad.